# TIZEN SDB Shell - input tap or touch screen command

Tags: linux, shell, tizen, tizen-sdb

I have experience in Android , just started in Tizen.
I know in Android for click/touch screen following command works.

```
adb shell input tap x y
```

Now in Tizen input command is not available.

I found [fMBT project's tizen-agent](https://github.com/01org/fMBT/blob/master/utils/fmbttizen-agent.py) , through which we can call:

```
sendHwFingerDown(x, y, button)
```

I want to know If there is any SDB or SDB Shell command for the same , to send events like click , touch up , touch down , drag , volume up , volume down , back , menu , power etc to the Tizen Device.

Thanks!

Comment: Tizen does not support such actions yet unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into the code, and it seems like you need to have root permissions on your device to use it. Basically it uses /dev/input/blabla, which doesn't work from plain sdb shell for my Gear 2 Neo (permission denied).

I work with Gear 2 Neo and for this device sdb doesn't allow root access, unless device is rooted.

My Gear is not rooted, so I cannot check if the fMBT code works. But if you root your device, it could work.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this as well when I stumbled into the shell of my tizen watch. By running `compgen -c | grep "input"` to list all available commands and filter it to only display input ones I found there is a command called `input_generator_tool` which can be used for example as:

```
input_generator_tool touch tap x y <repeats>
```

or

```
input_generator_tool touch swipe x1 y1 x2 y2
```

7 years later, hope this answers your question.